# mongdoDB Java query

Tags: java, mongodb

```
List<Document> docs = new ArrayList<>();

BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("publishedDateTime", "$gte:new Date(2019, 02, 25)");

for(Document doc:collection.find()) {
docs.add(doc);
}
```

I would like to filter out all documents where the publishedDateTime is greater than or equal to 25 Feb 2019. I do the following code as shown above.

The mongo db has documents where one of the field is

publishedDateTime: 2019-02-25 23:25:00.000

for example.

However, it returns nothing. How to get i write it correctly? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the new syntactic sugar provided by new mongo drivers:

```
    import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*;

    List<Document> docs = new ArrayList<>();
        collection.find(
                gte("publishedDateTime", 
                        LocalDate.of(2019, 02, 25)))
        .into(docs);
```

If you want to follow the old fashion way:

```
List<Document> docs = new ArrayList<>();

BasicDBObject filter = new BasicDBObject();
filter.put("publishedDateTime", new Document("$gte", LocalDate.of(2019, 02, 25));
// Do not forget to send the filter to the query!
for(Document doc:collection.find(filter)) {
   docs.add(doc);
}
```

Notice `Filter.gte` method is just a helper that makes same as this `filter.put("publishedDateTime", new Document("$gte", new Date(2019, 02, 25));` but looks more readable.

Comment: Hi i tried your method but nothing is retrieved. A document in the mongodb has the field publishedDateTime: 2019-02-25 23:25:00.000 as an example. This is of type Date as seen in my mongocompass. I don't know why nothing is being fetched.

Comment: Okay i realised i cant use new Date. I have to use LocalDate instead. Thanks!